# Issue in simple JavaScript "Web App"

Tags: javascript

I am working on a little project. It is about solving a math riddle. You can find the repo here: https://github.com/soulwash/how-many-soldiers

The problem occurs when I enter a number and click "Try". After I have done so I want to use the Buttons "Add +1", "Add +7" or "Next Higher Solution". The problem is that it is not just adding numbers but instead adding it at the end of the number creating a way higher amount.
For example:

Entering 290 -> then clicking Try -> then clicking "Add +1" -> it ends up with 2901 instead of 291

Same is with +7 and "Next Higher Solution" but not with the subtracting options.

Can you help me solve this issue?

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript auto convert data-type into string if first value is string. ex :

- var x = "5" + 2 + 3;   // output : 523
- var x = 5 + 2 + "3";   // output : 73
- var x = 5 + 2 + 3;     // output : 10

so check value again the " + operator " work with two type 
1) add 
2) concatenate the string

Best of Luck :)

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I only had to convert the user's input into a number at first... Now it works! But I still don't know why the subtraction part worket..

Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have your starting value as a string and trying to add to the string. When you add a number to a string you concatenate the string with that number ("71" + 6 becomes "716"). This is because + acts as addition and concatenation depending on how/when it's used. However, `-` acts differently. When you subtract JavaScript does a quick conversion of types and it does a numeric difference ("716" - 6 becomes 710 with 710 now being a type of number). Below is a quick example:

```js
var st = "71";

st = st + 6;

console.log(st);
console.log(typeof st);

st = st - 6;

console.log(st);
console.log(typeof st);
```

Comment: Alright, now I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In file `/src/app/howmanysoldiers.js` line `43` you use `let userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value`, but this is a string. Whats happening is like code bellow:

```
console.log('10' + 1) // '101'
console.log('10' - 1) // 9
```

To solve this situation you can try 2 different approaches

**Using parseInt**

```
let userInput = parseInt(document.getElementById("userInput").value) // And now it is a number
```

**Subtracting the value**

```
let userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value - 0 // And now it is a number
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Now I got it ;)